# Getting Metric 'files' should not be computed by a Sensor when sinning run-sonar-swift.sh -v

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Currently I am implementing SonarQube in project but after all setting I am getting error like

Running Lizard...Running SonarQube using SonarQube Runner..ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution

ERROR: Metric 'files' should not be computed by a Sensor
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
ERROR - Command 'sonar-scanner ' failed with error code: 1

Could you guys help me here please?

Comment: Are you using sonar-swift by any chance? If so, there's an issue for this on their GitHub: https://github.com/Backelite/sonar-swift/issues/212

Comment: Yes, I am using sonar-swift and I tried to use different version and I successfully. But  now, I am getting everything 0 like code smell and issues.